# Wrong Mouse position with different DPI settings in WPF

Tags: wpf, mouse, dpi

I am using the below code to get the current mouse position in a WPF application.

```
System.Drawing.Point _point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
```

This works good. But when the user has a 125% display settings in the machine (Windows 7), the mouse position is wrong. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

See if anything in this [Blog](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-reliably-getting-the-mouse-position) or this [Blog](http://wpftutorial.net/Mouse.html) helps and since you are using Wpf try using [Mouse.GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition.aspx) as in this modified MSDN example:

```
// displayArea is the main window and txtBoxMousePosition is
// a TextBox used to display the position of the mouse pointer.

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    txtBoxMousePosition.Text = "X: " + position.X + "\n" + "Y: " + position.Y; 
}
```

Comment: The first link (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-reliably-getting-the-mouse-position) is especially helpful, since I ran into the `Mouse.GetPosition()` not quite working issue.